# How to add markers to all series in an excel line chart in one go?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, formatting, charts

I have about 15 series in my chart and do not wish to manually select and edit each one individually to give it a distinct marker

Is there a way to do this for all lines in one go?

I don't care if the shape/type of marker is randomly assigned as long as they look different

Comment: It sounds like you selected a chart style with no markers.  If that's the case, just go back to "Select Chart Type" and pick a sub-style that shows markers on the icon.

Comment: How did I not see that?! Probably the same way I didn't notice the "text orientation" and "wrap text" buttons on the infuriatingly-non-customisable ribbon. Post as an answer and I will mark it as such, thanks!

Comment: An answer should be definitive, rather than a guess, which is what it would be if I post it.  It would be more appropriate for you to post the answer, saying that's what actually worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the loop on this question, I'll move a comment to an answer.  The problem appeared to describe selecting a chart style with no markers.  The solution to that is using the "Select Chart Type" button to pick a sub-style that shows markers on the icon.  Chart types can be changed after the chart is created.  The comments indicate that this was the issue.